# How to keep the TextField Values?

Tags: database, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, sqflite

how to keep the values inserted on a Text field knowing that the values are saved on a data base (wit sqflite)
the source code of the button that saves data

```
                MaterialButton(
                  elevation: 0,
                  minWidth: double.maxFinite,
                  height: 50,
                  onPressed: () async {
                   //setState(() {
                    var todoObject = Todo();
                   todoObject.datedebut =  _datecontroller.text;
                     todoObject.datefin= _datecontroller1.text;
                     todoObject.quantite= _quantitecontroller.text;

                     var _todoService = TodoService();
                     var  result = await _todoService.saveTodo(todoObject);

                     print(result);

                  // });
                  },
                  color: Colors.teal[200],
                  child: Text(
                    'Save',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 23,
                    ),
                  ),

                ),
```

Comment: Add the code of your `TextField` also.

Answer (score 0):

**I thin Onchanged Method can help**

in TextField we have a parameter called **onChnaged** u can use this parameter.

```
   onChanged:(value){

      }// save your data here.
```